# R/exams: How to change default "Exam 1" produced by exams2html

Tags: r-exams

Is there a way to change the "Exam 1" to another word like "Homework 1" by passing arguments?

If not, is there a default template I can modify?

My last resort is to modify the built html files but it's not very convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exams2html()` function takes an argument `template` which defaults to `"plain.html"`. This template is shipped with the `exams` package and contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<title>Exam ##ID##</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans;}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<h2>Exam ##ID##</h2>

##\exinput{exercises}##

</body>
</html>
```

The `##ID##` is replaced by the ID (from 1 to `n`) and the `##\exinput{exercises}##` is replaced by an ordered list `<ol>` containing the questions and optionally also the solutions. You can modify this template in any way you need and call it, say, `homework.html`. Then you can call:

```
exams2html(..., template = "/path/to/homework.html",
  question = "<h4>Exercise</h4>", solution = FALSE)
```

which sets the template and also modifies the way the question is displayed while suppressing the solution.

**Remark:** The placeholders `##ID##` and `##\exinput{exercises}##` are a bit awkward (analogous to the placeholders in LaTeX templates for `exams2pdf()`) and not very flexible. It has been on my wishlist to make this more flexible, e.g., using `{{mustache}}` templating via the `whisker` package, but so far I didn't get round to tackle that.